# Calculate the next and the 3rd business date from a given date

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am trying to implement a function to calculate the next and 3rd business day from a given date (ideally taking into account some given holidays)

```
def day_of_week(year, month, day):
t = [0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]
year -= month < 3
return (year + int(year/4) - int(year/100) + int(year/400) + t[month-1] + day) % 7
```

The input is in the format YYYYMMDD with 21th of March 2018 written as 20180321 and the output date should be in the same format.

I`m trying to do something like this but I realised this is not the best practice

```
def leap_year(year):
if(year%4==0 and year%100!=0):
    return True
elif (year%4==0 and year%100==0 and year%400==0):
    return True
else:
    return False

def business_day(year, month, day):
if (month==12):
    if(day_of_week(year, month, day)<5 and day_of_week(year, month, day)>0 and day==31):
        return str(year+1)+str(0)+str(1)+str(0)+str(1)
    elif (day_of_week(year, month, day)<5 and day_of_week(year, month, day)>0 and day!=31):
        newDay="0"
        if(day<10):
            newDay = newDay + str(day+1)
        else:
            newDay = str(day+1)
        return str(year) + str(month) + newDay
    elif (day_of_week(year, month, day)>=5 and day==31):
       if(day_of_week(year, month, day)==5):
            return str(year+1)+"01"+"03"
       if (day_of_week(year, month, day) == 6):
           return str(year + 1) + "01" + "02"
       if (day_of_week(year, month, day) == 0):
           return str(year + 1) + "01" + "01"
    elif (day_of_week(year, month, day)>=5 and day==30):
        if((day_of_week(year, month, day)==5)):
            return str(year + 1) + "01" + "02"
        if ((day_of_week(year, month, day) == 6)):
            return str(year + 1) + "01" + "01"
        if ((day_of_week(year, month, day) == 0)):
            return str(year + 1) + str(month) + str(day+1)
```

Can`t use any libraries in the solution. Thanks for the help

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: You need a function to convert a year-month-day into the number of days since some epoch (just pick a date like Jan 1, 1900), then a function to convert such a number back to a date. Once you have those functions, to add 3 days, just convert to a number, add 3, convert back. To handle weekends, you need a function that will, given a number, return how many days until the next business day. That probably looks similar to your day_of_week function.

Comment: This is the requirement: Algorithm that will calculate the date of the next business day after Friday the 28th of February 2020. The input date is provided as 20200228 and the answer should also be in the format YYYYMMDD

Comment: Side note- have you considered `day_name = day_of_week(year, month, day)` to save about 12 calls?

Comment: Not really, thanks for pointing that out @DillonDavis

Comment: Please do not delete your questions like that. Especially not if there are answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No libraries! I had some fun learning Python. Did you? :-)

```
def day_of_week(year, month, day):
    t = [0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]
    year -= month < 3
    dw = (year + year // 4 - year // 100 + year // 400 + t[month-1] + day) % 7
    return [6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5][dw]  # To be consistent with 'datetime' library


def leap_year(year):
    leap = year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
    return True if leap else False


def valid_day(year, month, day):
    month_list = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if year < 1 or year > 9999 or month < 1 or month > 12:
        return False
    m = month_list[month-1] if month != 2 or not leap_year(year) else 29
    return True if 1 <= day <= m else False


class Career(Exception):
        def __str__(self): return 'So I became a waiter...'


MAX_DATE_AND_DAYS_INT = 365 * 100


class Date:
    #         raise ValueError

    def __init__(self, year, month, day):
        if not valid_day(year, month, day):
            raise Career()
        self.y, self.m, self.d = year, month, day

    @classmethod
    def fromstring(cls, s):
        s1, s2, s3 = int(s[0:4]), int(s[4:6]), int(s[6:8])
        return cls(s1, s2, s3)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return '%04d%02d%02d' % (self.y, self.m, self.d)

    def weekday_date(self) -> str:
        names = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
        return names[self.weekday()] + ' ' + str(self)

    def next_day(self):
        if valid_day(self.y, self.m, self.d + 1):
            return Date(self.y, self.m, self.d + 1)
        elif valid_day(self.y, self.m + 1, 1):
            return Date(self.y, self.m + 1, 1)
        elif valid_day(self.y + 1, 1, 1):
            return Date(self.y + 1, 1, 1)
        else:
            raise Career

    def weekday(self):
        return day_of_week(self.y, self.m, self.d)

    def __add__(self, other):
        "Add a Date to an int."
        if isinstance(other, int):
            if other < 1 or other > MAX_DATE_AND_DAYS_INT:
                raise OverflowError("int > MAX_DATE_AND_DAYS_INT")
            new_date = Date(self.y, self.m, self.d)
            while other >= 1:
                new_date = new_date.next_day()
                other -= 1
            return new_date
        return NotImplemented

    def next_working_day(self):
        day = self.next_day()
        while True:
            while day.weekday() >= 5:
                day = day.next_day()
            holidays_list = year_holidays(day.y)
            for str_day in holidays_list:
                s2 = str(day)
                if str_day == s2:
                    day = day.next_day()
                    break  # for
            if day.weekday() < 5:
                break  # while True
        return day


def year_holidays(year):
    holidays = [
        ["New Year's Day", 1, 1],  # Fixed: January 1
        ["Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.", 1, 0, 0, 3],  # Floating
        ["Washington's Birthday", 2, 0, 0, 3],  # Third Monday in February
        ["Memorial Day", 5, 0, 0, 5],  # Last Monday
        ["Independence Day", 7, 4],
        ["Labor Day", 9, 0, 0, 1],
        ["Columbus Day", 10, 0, 0, 2],
        ["Veterans Day", 11, 11],
        ["Thanksgiving Day", 11, 0, 3, 4],
        ["Christmas Day", 12, 25]
    ]
    year_list = []
    for h in holidays:
        if h[2] > 0:
            day = Date(year, h[1], h[2])  # Fixed day
        else:
            day = Date(year, h[1], 1)  # Floating day
            while h[3] != day.weekday():  # Advance to match the weekday
                day = day.next_day()
            count = 1
            while count != h[4]:  # Match the repetition of this day
                next_week = day + 7
                if next_week.m == day.m:
                    day = next_week
                count += 1
        year_list.append(str(day))
    return year_list  # return the holidays as list of strings


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dates = [
        ['20190308', '20190311', '20190313'],
        ['20190309', '20190311', '20190313'],
        ['20190310', '20190311', '20190313'],
        ['20190311', '20190312', '20190314'],
        ['20190329', '20190401', '20190403'],
        ['20181231', '20190102', '20190104'],
        ['20190118', '20190122', '20190124'],
        ['20190216', '20190219', '20190221'],
        ['20190526', '20190528', '20190530'],
        ['20190703', '20190705', '20190709'],
        ['20190828', '20190829', '20190903'],
        ['20191010', '20191011', '20191016'],
        ['20191108', '20191112', '20191114'],
        ['20191125', '20191126', '20191129'],
        ['20191224', '20191226', '20191230'],
        ['20191227', '20191230', '20200102']]
    print('\n              Today        Next   and   3rd business day')
    for days in dates:
        today = Date.fromstring(days[0])
        next_day = today.next_working_day()
        third_day = next_day.next_working_day().next_working_day()
        if str(next_day) != days[1] or str(third_day) != days[2]:
            print('*** ERROR *** ', end='')
        else:
            print('              ', end='')
        print(today.weekday_date(), next_day.weekday_date(), third_day.weekday_date())
```

Output:

```
          Today        Next   and   3rd business day
          Fri 20190308 Mon 20190311 Wed 20190313
          Sat 20190309 Mon 20190311 Wed 20190313
          Sun 20190310 Mon 20190311 Wed 20190313
          Mon 20190311 Tue 20190312 Thu 20190314
          Fri 20190329 Mon 20190401 Wed 20190403
          Mon 20181231 Wed 20190102 Fri 20190104
          Fri 20190118 Tue 20190122 Thu 20190124
          Sat 20190216 Tue 20190219 Thu 20190221
          Sun 20190526 Tue 20190528 Thu 20190530
          Wed 20190703 Fri 20190705 Tue 20190709
          Wed 20190828 Thu 20190829 Tue 20190903
          Thu 20191010 Fri 20191011 Wed 20191016
          Fri 20191108 Tue 20191112 Thu 20191114
          Mon 20191125 Tue 20191126 Fri 20191129
          Tue 20191224 Thu 20191226 Mon 20191230
          Fri 20191227 Mon 20191230 Thu 20200102
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime


example = '20180321'
# you can parse the time string directly to a datetime object
next_buisness_day = datetime.datetime.strptime(example, '%Y%m%d')
# specify the increment based on the day of the week or any
#other condition
increment = 1
print('day day is', next_buisness_day.weekday())
# if friday
if next_buisness_day.weekday() == 4:
    increment = 3
# if saturday
elif next_buisness_day.weekday() == 5:
    increment = 2

next_buisness_day += datetime.timedelta(days=increment)
# and convert back to whatever format you like
print('{:%Y%m%d}'.format(next_buisness_day))
```

Have  a look at the datetime module you can do all sorts of things with it.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

I use few functions from 'datetime' library. You can have fun to write them: date(y, m, d), timedelta(days=7), day,weekday(), '{:%Y%m%d}'.format(day), strptime(input, '%Y%m%d'), strftime(datetime, '%a %x'). Good idea is to create a class for date and get rid from all format conversions. So, only date(y, m, d), timedelta(days=7), day, weekday() will be left for exercise.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta


def day2string(day):
    return '{:%Y%m%d}'.format(day)


def year_holidays(year):
    holidays = [
        ["New Year's Day", 1, 1],  # Fixed: January 1
        ["Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.", 1, 0, 0, 3],  # Floating
        ["Washington's Birthday", 2, 0, 0, 3],  # Third Monday in February
        ["Memorial Day", 5, 0, 0, 5],  # Last Monday
        ["Independence Day", 7, 4],
        ["Labor Day", 9, 0, 0, 1],
        ["Columbus Day", 10, 0, 0, 2],
        ["Veterans Day", 11, 11],
        ["Thanksgiving Day", 11, 0, 3, 4],
        ["Christmas Day", 12, 25]
    ]
    year_list = []
    for h in holidays:
        if h[2] > 0:
            day = date(year, h[1], h[2])  # Fixed day
        else:
            day = date(year, h[1], 1)  # Floating day
            while h[3] != day.weekday():  # Advance to match the weekday
                day += timedelta(days=1)
            count = 1
            while count != h[4]:  # Match the repetition of this day
                next_week = day + timedelta(days=7)
                if next_week.month == day.month:
                    day = next_week
                count += 1
        year_list.append(day2string(day))
    return year_list  # return the holidays as list of strings


def str2datetime(string):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%Y%m%d')


def next_working_day(string):
    day = str2datetime(string)
    day += timedelta(days=1)
    while True:
        while day.weekday() >= 5:
            day += timedelta(days=1)
        holidays_list = year_holidays(day.year)
        for str_day in holidays_list:
            s2 = day2string(day)
            if str_day == s2:
                day += timedelta(days=1)
                break  # for
        if day.weekday() < 5:
            break  # while True
    return day2string(day)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dates = [
        ['20190308', '20190311', '20190313'],
        ['20190309', '20190311', '20190313'],
        ['20190310', '20190311', '20190313'],
        ['20190311', '20190312', '20190314'],
        ['20190329', '20190401', '20190403'],
        ['20181231', '20190102', '20190104'],
        ['20190118', '20190122', '20190124'],
        ['20190216', '20190219', '20190221'],
        ['20190526', '20190528', '20190530'],
        ['20190703', '20190705', '20190709'],
        ['20190828', '20190829', '20190903'],
        ['20191010', '20191011', '20191016'],
        ['20191108', '20191112', '20191114'],
        ['20191125', '20191126', '20191129'],
        ['20191224', '20191226', '20191230'],
        ['20191227', '20191230', '20200102']]
    print('\n              Today        Next   and   3rd business day')
    for days in dates:
        next_day = next_working_day(days[0])
        third_day = next_working_day(next_working_day(next_day))
        if next_day != days[1] or third_day != days[2]:
            print('*** ERROR *** ', end='')
        else:
            print('              ', end='')

        def f(x): return datetime.datetime.strftime(str2datetime(x), '%a %x')

        print(f(days[0]), f(next_day), f(third_day))
```

It should create the next output:

```
          Today        Next   and   3rd business day
          Fri 03/08/19 Mon 03/11/19 Wed 03/13/19
          Sat 03/09/19 Mon 03/11/19 Wed 03/13/19
          Sun 03/10/19 Mon 03/11/19 Wed 03/13/19
          Mon 03/11/19 Tue 03/12/19 Thu 03/14/19
          Fri 03/29/19 Mon 04/01/19 Wed 04/03/19
          Mon 12/31/18 Wed 01/02/19 Fri 01/04/19
          Fri 01/18/19 Tue 01/22/19 Thu 01/24/19
          Sat 02/16/19 Tue 02/19/19 Thu 02/21/19
          Sun 05/26/19 Tue 05/28/19 Thu 05/30/19
          Wed 07/03/19 Fri 07/05/19 Tue 07/09/19
          Wed 08/28/19 Thu 08/29/19 Tue 09/03/19
          Thu 10/10/19 Fri 10/11/19 Wed 10/16/19
          Fri 11/08/19 Tue 11/12/19 Thu 11/14/19
          Mon 11/25/19 Tue 11/26/19 Fri 11/29/19
          Tue 12/24/19 Thu 12/26/19 Mon 12/30/19
          Fri 12/27/19 Mon 12/30/19 Thu 01/02/20
```